# Publish RemoteApp of IIS manager from multiple servers

Tags: rds, iis, windows

I have a couple servers running with IIS 8 running on them.
One is a public server with RDS running on it. I have published the IIS manager as a remote app from this server, but I would also like to publish the IIS managers from the other two servers for use by the Developers security group. What would be the best approach to do this? This is my first foray into RDS and remote apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing up a couple configuration issues that were obfuscating the issue, it was actually quite easy.

- Created a new MMC added 3 instances of IIS manager.
- Connected each one to one of my 3 servers.
- Saved the MMC to a share.
- Added it to the list of publishable RemoteApps with a UNC path.
- Published to the collection I set up for developers.